# Keyboard issue while focusing on bottom edit text in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-keypad

I am working on an android Application where I am willing to get input from user. I created a layout for it which has a scroll view as a root view & Relative layout as it's child all the other layout are inside this Relative layout. But when edit text is at the bottom of screen & user click on it to bring keyboard it shows some blank box between edit text & keyboard & after this if user enters any word it doesn't get displayed in edit text. But if Edit text is above nearly more then half size of screen it works fine. You can get more clearly by looking at images below

[Here is my code](http://pastebin.com/t4dcpqNn)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Does anyone faced this kind of problem?? Please help!!!

Comment: Where is this blank box? Could you please outline it?

Comment: @a.ch. -- blank place just below Edit text in second image

Comment: It is the black area, right? Then you should provide your layout's xml-file.

Comment: Have you tried this on an actual device?

Comment: @JasonRobinson -- yes same result

Comment: Your source is probably the largest layout file I've ever seen. There's no tellings what's in there that might be causing this. I would invest in cleaning that up, because I don't know who's going to be willing to sift through all that.

Comment: Try android:fadingEdge="none" for scrollbar

Comment: Try removing the bunch of the views leaving few of them and see if it solves the problem. Otherwise it would take ages to debug those 1001 lines of code.

Comment: @a.ch. -- I checked by added Edit text in Linear View such as they will go below screen (Without Scroll view) & got same error.

Comment: what's going on at line 239/240? Looks like you're trying to merge two layouts (from different files) into one? If that is the case, you're doing it wrong. If it isn't, you should check the code you provide for people to solve issues you have for errors. Agree totally with @JasonRobinson though; far too large for us to read, and you to maintain.

Comment: @timberwo7ves -- code updated Sorry for previous code as wrong copy paste was there

Comment: have you tried using the HierarchyViewer while the black bit is showing to see if it points to an element in your activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default IME mode set on the activity in the manifest (*android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"*) will pan the main layout so the text field is in the middle of the viewable area. While the majority of your content is in a scrollable region, it is simply moving the whole region and not scrolling the contents into view. If you use *android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"* it will prevent the layout panning, but will also effectively do nothing and just cover your original input.

MY recommendation would be to use adjustResize, this might fix it for you. If not, you have to look into doing some custom scroll-region focusing.

Comment: For info: "adjustNothing" is not accepted (-> string types not allowed) by the latest SDK and tools, despite what the docs say. I suppose "adjustResize|adjustPan" will have the same effect though. Must be a bug I guess.

Comment: true. yeah adjustResize should probably do the trick. As long as the input box stays put