# keyboard overlaps Edit Text on tablelayout

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, android-keypad

I have a Fullscreen dialog fragment with a Spinner and a Tablelayout.
I can add elements to the tablelayout by selecting an option of the Spinner. Those elements are cardviews that are inflated into the tablelayout (let's don't argue about why I chose this instead of recyclerview or listview)
I have two problems
number one: 
the views are not matching with its parent width (there is a blank space to the right of each element)

number two:
Every element of the tablelayout has an Edit text field. If i add several elements, the keyboard overlaps the last edittexts.
How can i solve those problems. I am beggining android

[image: keyboard overlaps]
here is my code
**Dialog_search_contract.java**

```
public class Dialog_search_contract  extends DialogFragment {

    //private Arraylist<>
    private static final String TAG = "AKDialogFragment";
    private View view_search;
   private TableLayout tabla;
    private Dialog_manager dm=Dialog_manager.getDialog_manager();
    private TableRow fila;
   private final TableRow.LayoutParams layoutFila = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    private final TableRow.LayoutParams layout_celda = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    boolean flags[];

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (getActivity()instanceof Comercial) {
            view_search = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_contract_comercial, container, false);
        }
        else{
            view_search = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_contract, container, false);

        }


        tabla = (TableLayout) view_search.findViewById(R.id.table_search);
        tabla.setLayoutParams(layout_celda);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view_search.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_search_contract);
        toolbar.setTitle("Buscar contrato");
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel);
        }
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        Spinner opcion = (Spinner) view_search.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> staticAdapter = ArrayAdapter
                .createFromResource(view_search.getContext(), R.array.contract_search,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        staticAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        opcion.setAdapter(staticAdapter);
        opcion.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                       int position, long id) {
                addCriteria(position);

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        return view_search;
    }


    public void addCriteria(int position) {

            Filtro_contract aux= getOption(position);
            View tr= createView(aux,position);
             addTextField(aux,tr);
             addRemoveButton(tr);
            addSpinner(aux,tr);
             addOptionText(aux,tr);

            tabla.addView(tr);

        }


    private View createView(Filtro_contract filter, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        View tr = null;
                inflater=LayoutInflater.from(view_search.getContext());
                tr = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview_search, null,false);
        tr.setId(position);
        tr.setLayoutParams(layoutFila);

        return tr;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        menu.clear();
        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_contract_menu, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_search) {

            sendQuery();
            return true;
        } else if (id == android.R.id.home) {

            dismiss();
            dm.closeDialog();
            Log.d("--","Se ha cerrado el dialogo Dialog_search_contract");
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void sendQuery() {
        Context context=getActivity();
        Contract_query_instance.setContract_query_instance(generateQuery());

        if (getActivity()instanceof Comercial) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, Result_contract.class);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
        else{
            ((Result_contract)getActivity()).load_data();
        }


        dm.closeDialog();
        dismiss();
    }

    public Contract_query generateQuery()
    {  ArrayList<Contract_condition> condiciones= new ArrayList<Contract_condition>();

        for (int i = 0; i < tabla.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View criterio= tabla.getChildAt(i);
            int id=criterio.getId();
            Filtro_contract filtro=getOption(id);

            Spinner sp=(Spinner)criterio.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            int cond=sp.getSelectedItemPosition();
            Compare compare= getCompare(cond,filtro);


            EditText txt= (EditText)criterio.findViewById(R.id.texto);
            String texto= String.valueOf(txt.getText());



            if ((!sonEspacios(texto)&& texto!=null)
                    || compare==Compare.NOT_STABLISHED
                    || compare==compare.STABLISHED ) {

                //Reemplaza varios espacios por uno y elimina los del comienzo y el final
                String text = texto.replaceAll(" +", " ").trim();
                if (filtro==Filtro_contract.SIGNING_DATE||filtro==Filtro_contract.DUE_DATE)
                {

                    Date fecha= FormatDate.parse_from_dd_MM_yy(text);
                    text=FormatDate.format_to_yyyy_MM_dd(fecha);
                }

                condiciones.add(new Contract_condition(filtro, compare, text));
            }
        }
        Contract_query qry= new Contract_query(condiciones);
        Log.d("Se ha generado la ","consulta");
           return qry;
    }
}
```

**search_contract.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
       android:fitsSystemWindows="false" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_search_contract"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Agregar Condición"
            android:id="@+id/agregarCondicionText" />

        <Spinner android:text="@string/opcion"
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />




    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollvertical_search_contract"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/scrollhorizontal_search_contract"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TableLayout android:id="@+id/table_search"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:stretchColumns="1">
                </TableLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </ScrollView>



    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**cardview_search.xml**

**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@style/cardview_header"
            android:text="filtro"
            android:id="@+id/filtro"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/boton_cerrar"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_close_box"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
        <Spinner android:text="@string/opcion"
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/linea"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/texto"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/spinner"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/spinner"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/spinner"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            />
        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#ffd5d5d5"
            android:id="@+id/linea"
            android:layout_below="@+id/filtro"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"></View>
        <!--ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/estado"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            /-->
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**

Comment: For the blank space, you are setting the width yourself `android:layout_width="150dp"`. Try maybe to set the parent and child layout to `match_parent`

Comment: For you question #2, I am not sure if I understand well but it sound like you might want to look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10097160/1245894

Comment: In the AndroidManifest file put this line android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" as an atribute on the activity

Comment: Actually i think You need adjustResize instead of adjustPan

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:**

Try using `android:layout_width="match_parent"` to your `CardView` and `RelativeLayout`:

**cardview_search.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@style/cardview_header"
            android:text="filtro"
            android:id="@+id/filtro"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/boton_cerrar"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_close_box"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
        <Spinner android:text="@string/opcion"
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/linea"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/texto"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/spinner"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/spinner"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/spinner"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            />
        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#ffd5d5d5"
            android:id="@+id/linea"
            android:layout_below="@+id/filtro"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"></View>
        <!--ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/estado"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            /-->
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**Question 2:**

Remove `android:layout_weight="1"` from `ScrollView`